# SQL Server relations between two table by xml type coumn and output xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I'm trying write a query, but I have not been successful yet. I need some help if possible.

I have 2 tables, `Category` and `Product`.

**Category** Table

Columns: Id int, ParentID int, XmlData XML

```
INSERT INTO Category
VALUES (1, 0,
'<category>
   <item>BMW</item>
   <item>MERCEDES</item>
   <item>AUDI</item>
   <item>WOLKSVAGEN</item>
</category>')
```

**Product** table:

Columns Id int, XmlData xml

```
INSERT INTO Product 
VALUES (1, '<item>
    <category id="1" />
    <name>Carburetor</name>
    <model>MDS343498</model>
    <price>$3000</price>
    <stock>123</stock>
</item>')
```

I want to merge related two XML column.

I want output like this:

```
'<item>
    <category id="1">
        <item>BMW</item>
        <item>MERCEDES</item>
        <item>AUDI</item>
        <item>WOLKSVAGEN</item>
    </category>
    <name>Carburetor</name>
    <model>MDS343498</model>
    <price>$3000</price>
    <stock>123</stock>
</item>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit tricky to replace one node with another node. The following code will use an *updateable CTE* first to find the fitting `category`, fetch its `XmlData` and then use the CTE to `UPDATE` the product's `XmlData` and `insert` the new node.

The problem we now is: The category exists twice: Once as new node and the second time as the old node. As we inserted `as first` we can be sure, that the second occurance is the one to remove:

```
DECLARE @Category Table(Id int, ParentID int, XmlData XML);
INSERT INTO @Category
VALUES (
1, 
0,
'<category>
   <item>BMW</item>
   <item>MERCEDES</item>
   <item>AUDI</item>
   <item>WOLKSVAGEN</item>
</category>'
);

DECLARE @Product Table (Id int, XmlData xml);

INSERT INTO @Product 
VALUES (
1,
'<item>
    <category id="1" />
    <name>Carburetor</name>
    <model>MDS343498</model>
    <price>$3000</price>
    <stock>123</stock>
</item>'
);
```

--The updateable CTE

```
WITH UpdateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT p.Id
          ,p.XmlData
          ,Cat.XmlData AS XmlToInsert
    FROM @Product AS p
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.XmlData FROM @Category AS c WHERE Id=p.XmlData.value('(/item/category/@id)[1]','int')) AS Cat
)
UPDATE UpdateableCTE
SET XmlData.modify(N'insert sql:column("XmlToInsert") as first into (/item)[1]');
```

--remove the second occurance

```
UPDATE @Product SET XmlData.modify(N'delete /item[1]/category[2]')
```

--The result in XmlData:

```
SELECT * FROM @Product

<item>
  <category>
    <item>BMW</item>
    <item>MERCEDES</item>
    <item>AUDI</item>
    <item>WOLKSVAGEN</item>
  </category>
  <name>Carburetor</name>
  <model>MDS343498</model>
  <price>$3000</price>
  <stock>123</stock>
</item>
```

OT: You probably want to correct `WOLKSVAGEN` to `VOLKSWAGEN` :-)

### UPDATE Keep the attribute `<category id="1">`, which got lost in the upper approach:

I use a `FLWOR`-query to pre-organise the `XmlToInsert`

```
WITH UpdateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT p.Id
          ,p.XmlData
          ,Cat.XmlData.query
          (
          N'<category id="{sql:column("CatId")}">
            {/category/item}
            </category>'
          ) AS XmlToInsert
    FROM @Product AS p
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.Id AS CatId, c.XmlData FROM @Category AS c WHERE Id=p.XmlData.value('(/item/category/@id)[1]','int')) AS Cat
)
UPDATE UpdateableCTE
SET XmlData.modify(N'insert sql:column("XmlToInsert") as first into (/item)[1]');

UPDATE @Product SET XmlData.modify(N'delete /item[1]/category[2]')

SELECT * FROM @Product
```

### UPDATE 2: Differen approach *on the fly*

Try it like this

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT p.Id
          ,p.XmlData
          ,Cat.XmlData.query
          (
          N'<category id="{sql:column("CatId")}">
            {/category/item}
            </category>'
          ) AS XmlToInsert
    FROM @Product AS p
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 c.Id AS CatId, c.XmlData FROM @Category AS c WHERE Id=p.XmlData.value('(/item/category/@id)[1]','int')) AS Cat
)
SELECT XmlToInsert AS [node()]
      ,XmlData.query('/item/*[local-name()!="category"]')
FROM CTE
FOR XML PATH('item')
```

Comment: Thanks :-), But can you do without declaration. Tables already exists.

Comment: @Uysal, that's easy... Just start with the `WITH ...` and change the table's names (`@Product` and `@Category`) to your actual table's names. The *declared table variables* are just a *mock-up* to create a test scenario.

Comment: I don't want update data on table, I want on the fly result.

Comment: @Uysal see my UPDATE 2

Comment: @Uysal Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Comment: Yes its working but XmlToInsert bad for my table. Have many attributes in category node, its all removed. I want put the category table as xml in categoy node. Without changing. I am looking more efficient method.

Comment: @Uysal. I'd say: **This question** is solved. In your question there is no other attribute, therefore my answer fully solves the given example... Please allow me one hint: One principle on SO is: **One issue - one question**. It would be very kind of you to close this with acceptance and start a new question with a better example, expected output and a link to this question. SO's helping armada will rush in quickly...